# 400 bad request on post

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

Trying to send a request from my factory to the back end, getting the following error: POST http://localhost:8000/messages/58d4b22d57f49028608f7bf9 400 (Bad Request)

Factory:

```
app.factory('usersFactory', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};
    var current_user = [];

    factory.login = function (data, callback) {
        $http.post('/users/', data)
            .then(function (response) {
                current_user.push(response.data);
                callback(current_user);
            })
    };

    factory.getUser = function (callback) {
        callback(current_user);
    }

    factory.destroy = function (callback) {
        current_user = [];
        callback();
    }

    factory.writePost = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(current_user[0]._id)
        $http.post('/messages/' + current_user[0]._id, data)
            .then(function (response) {
                $location.url('/wall');
            })
    }

    return factory;
});
```

Server routes:

```
var wall = require('./../controllers/serverController.js')

module.exports = function(app){
    app.post('/users/', function (request, response) {        
        wall.login(request, response);
    });
    app.post('/messsage/:id', function (request, response) {
        wall.writeMessage(request, response);
    })
}
```

Sever controller:

```
module.exports =
{
 writeMessage: function (request, response) {
     User.findOne({ _id: request.params.id }, function (err, user) {
         var message = new Message({ message: request.body, _user: request.params.id });
         message.save(function (err) {
             user.messages.push(message);
             user.save(function (err) {
                 if (err) {
                     response.json(err);
                 }
             })
         })
     })
 }
}
```

Comment: try to debug your code

Answer (score 0):

this is error of sever side not angular, try to check logs of server.

Also you are using Message , do have schema imported in that ?

Comment: How is this an answer

Comment: 400 means normally that server response an error due to some reason , it can't be angular error

Comment: if you got error from postman , then please post model file with controller js file , i will let you the error then

Comment: "please make sure using postman , that api is working" ... you mentioned postman. Why wouldn't Fiddler, or Rest Client work? also, this answer is crap in general. Downvoted